# Typing functions that operate on similar recursive types

Tags: typescript, recursion, functional-programming, algebraic-data-types

In the following Typescript code, I have two structurally similar types: `Nat`, which is either a `Zero` or a `Succ<Nat>`, and `Letter`, which is either a `A` or a `Succ<Letter>`, where `Succ` is a simple container type.

```js
type Zero = 0;
type A = 'A';

class Succ<T> {
  constructor(public pred: T){}
}

type Nat= Zero | Succ<Nat>

type Letter = A | Succ<Letter>

function next(x: ?): ?{
  return new Succ(x);
}
```

My question is, how do I type the `next` function, which is basically just the constructor for `Succ` wrapped in a function call? Essentially to declare that if you pass in a `Nat` you get back a `Nat` and if you pass in a `Letter` you get back a `Letter`.

I tried:

```
type Countable = Nat | Letter
function next<T extends Countable>(x: T): T { ...
```

And I'm getting `Type 'Succ<T>' is not assignable to type 'T'. 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'Succ<T>'.`

I also tried overloading it directly:

```js
function next(x: Nat): Nat;
function next(x: Letter): Letter {
  return new Succ(x);
}
```

But that returns an error that the signature is incompatible with the implementation.

I tried casting it directly:

```js
function next<T extends Countable>(x: T): T {
  return new Succ(x) as T;
}
```

That returns an error that `Conversion of type 'Succ<T>' to type 'T' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first. 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'Succ<T>'.`

So I did: `return new Succ(x) as unknown as T;`

That *worked*, but it feels very dirty (it feels like casting to void and back). As a sanity check, `const x: Letter = next(0);` correctly throws a type error that `Type '0' is not assignable to type 'Letter'.`

What's going on here? Am I on the write track? Is there a more elegant solution?

**Context:**

I'm working on a lambda calculus interpreter, out of *The Implementation of Functional Programming Languages*. There are a couple of different ASTs -- the core lambda calculus, the core lambda calculus + `let` expressions, the core lambda calculus + `let` + pattern matching, etc. Currently the way I have it set up is that each construct is a class, and the recursive ones take the type for the AST as a parameter so we have `Variable`, `Abstraction<AST>`, `Application<AST>`, `Let<AST>`, etc, and then each different type of AST is expressed as a union, so

```
type OrdinaryLambdaCalculus = 
  | Variable 
  | Abstraction<OrdinaryLambdaCalculus> 
  | Application<OrdinaryLambdaCalculus>;

type AugmentedLambdaCalculus = 
  | Variable 
  | Abstraction<AugmentedLambdaCalculus> 
  | Application<AugmentedLambdaCalculus>
  | Let<AugmentedLambdaCalculus>
```

It's working fairly well so far, but I'd like to be able to write a function that takes one or more AST expressions, and constructs a new AST of the same type by adding structure, so for instance:

```
function etaAbstraction<T extends AST>(ast: T): T {
  let newVar = findFree(ast);
  return new Abstraction(newVar, new Application(ast, newVar));
}
```

And that's where I'm running into trouble getting the types correct.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that this:

```
function next<T extends Countable>(x: T): T {
  return new Succ(x)
}
```

doesn't work is that if `x` (and therefore `T`) is of type `Zero` or `A`, then the return value must be the same. But `Succ<Whatever>` is not assignable to `Zero` or `A`.

However, it seems like `next` could never return `Zero` or `A`, only an instance of `Succ`. So if you type it as such, it works like you expect.

```
type Countable = Nat | Letter

function next<T extends Countable>(x: T): Succ<T> {
  return new Succ(x);
}

const a = next(0) // Succ<0>
const b = next(a) // Succ<Succ<0>>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAWhBOB7KBeKAGA3AWAFCkigEFUoByIsnXPAYwBsBDAZ2agGUBXW2gHgBUAfFADeeKFFqIAds2DxuwRPAAUYTgCN6AS1pQw8CABMAXFH4BKEQF88tmvnDQAco2Ck4SKAB8O3Pq7AgngE0AAyEMDACKQkvlw8vBFRCMGOhADCiJzSwIxa0GiBPlDJ0fB4eABmObTA2jJQ0hAAHsACUK3R0kZsWTl5BYIqLWaWZgl8QqLiUIbAnPDSTRAA7n48IxbU9nQyclCMpM1tKugWUAD0lxt86GlSsu4ax10qjBfXt7yTvPeCQA)

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for your help. Is there any way to express the transitivity that I am looking for? Where if `T = Zero`, by `Nat = Zero ...` and by `Nat = Succ<Nat>`, `T = Succ<Zero>` where `=` is a type equivalency. I'm thinking about situations where the return type might be way more complicated, but should still be equivalent to T. For example, peano arithmetic could get into situations where I can't know at compile time what the literal type is, but I can guarantee that it is equivalent to T.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, but `Zero` could never be the same type as `Succ<Zero>`. One is a number, and one is an instance. You may be able to have an API where you pass in a literal to get things started, but like the `next` function, it should always be an instance of `Succ` from there on. But in case I totally misunderstood, please clarify.

Comment: Are `Zero` and `Succ<Zero>` not both members of `Nat`? Since `Nat` is defined by `type Nat = Zero | Succ<Nat>`. I can write a function that takes `Nat` and returns `Nat`, which will take `Zero` and returns `Succ<Zero>`. I can also write a function that takes `Letter` and returns a `Letter` along the same lines. In fact, I'd write both functions with exactly the same body: `return new Succ(x)`. Now imagine the function `add = (x,y) => x instanceof Succ ? new Succ(add(x.pred, y)) : y`. It similarly works for both `Nat` and `Letter` but I can't write a type that expresses that.